# Checking condition and calling continuous method with periods of delay unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delay

I want code to check if target is alive, and if yes shoot at it.
I want to check it all the time, and shoot all the time, The only problem is that checks can be made anytime u want, but shooting must have limits of fire per second. I mean u check the target all the time, but when u decide to shoot, bullets will fire one after another with some delays. And also when u realize that target is dead u stop shooting at the same time.

```
void Update()
{
   StartCoroutine(Shoot(currentTarget, 1f));
}

IEnumerator Shoot(Collider currentTarget, float delayTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
    if (currentTarget != null)
    {
         .......
    }
}
```

This code starts to shoot but with no delays between shooting.

Comment: never use coroutines.  use Invoke or InvokeRepeating

Comment: I did but invoke method could not be called because shoot method had parameter inside. 
Invoke("Shoot(currentTarget)", 3 );
This code was not invoking shoot

Comment: Few questions for you. What do you mean by alive? I assume that currentTarget is the target. How do you know when the target is dead?

Comment: I actually *would not put* the currentTarget as an argument to the Shoot function

Comment: @JoeBlow why not use coroutines? Unity's virtual reality samples heavily uses them and not invoke

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Never never ever use coroutines.  They teach bad habits from the point of view as a c# developer and will lead to a lynching if you take a regular c# job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InvokeRepeating( "PossiblyShoot" , 1f, 1f );

private void PossiblyShoot()
   {
   1. check if target still exists
   2. if it exists shoot at it
   }
```

Comment: Perfect. Also I had to move Invoke from Update function to start and now it's working fine! Thanks!

Comment: lol no worries .. enjoy yourself.  don't believe anything you see in Unity doco