# C# Why shouldn't I ever use coroutines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

One of the comments on this thread: [Checking condition and calling continuous method with periods of delay unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807232/checking-condition-and-calling-continuous-method-with-periods-of-delay-unity?noredirect=1#comment59286425_35807232), said that:

> Never never ever use coroutines. They teach bad habits from the point of view as a c# developer and will lead to a lynching if you take a regular c# job

My question is, why is this? Is this just in Unity or in general? Unity's official virtual reality samples https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/51519 use them very heavily (especially the flyer example) instead of Invoke or Invoke Repeating, these sample projects were released recently as well.

Comment: Hi Martin, additional to Cory's explanation, quite simply ***for beginners*** in 99% of cases the only reason the person uses a coroutine is, incredibly simply that, ***they do not realise there is an Invoke and InvokeRepeating call*** or secondly that ***they just don't know about the Update call***, in Unity.  it's honestly just that simple. Note that (if you're an expert) you ***have to*** use Invoke/Repeating where appropriate, and you fully understand that Update and a Coroutine ***are the same thing***.

Comment: To make something of an analogy, it's a bit like the "++" operator in c.  (a) it's a staggeringly bad idea, the single worst idea in software engineering (b) of 1000 hobbyist beginners, maybe 2 have a clue what it means, the difference between ++a and a++, and other subtleties (c) *sure*, sometimes experts will use it as a sort of shorthand to indicate an algorithm, or the like.

Comment: (You mention "unity's lol samples", all unity docu and samples are beyond a joke, an industry legend in worthlessness. Note too that that is a *virtual reality* sample, for goodness sake:  99.999% of *beginner* questions relating to "coroutines!" are like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35807346/294884 )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very much a Unity thing, though the advice is applicable anywhere.

Developers do not expect iterating an `IEnumerable` to change a program's state. It's not what `IEnumerable` is intended for and is an inconsistent behavior with all of .NET.

What Unity is doing is using `yield return` as a pseudo-coroutine, and it's going to cause confusion for any devs unfamiliar with that.

In modern C# we have async/await to accomplish what Unity intended, but Unity was made before that feature was available.

Comment: While it is very easy to build a coroutine with `yield`, how would you build it with `async`/`await`? Interestingly the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#Implementations_for_C.23) lists the `yield` pattern as a semi-coroutine pattern, but doesn't list `async`/`await`.

Comment: Cory, while all true do bear in mind though that  Unity is an ECS frame-based system; they are "twisting" the whole thing a bit to mean, nothing more than, "go to next frame".  (I have no clue why it exists, since Update is identical ... i.e. access the next frame; sure, it's convenient but is the chaos worth it?)  You are of course incredibly correct that 99% of people think "coroutines!" in Unity have something to do with **threading/timing/waiting**. Of course, coroutines have nothing to do with those issues, at all.

Comment: @Fattie i did not imply that coroutines have anything intrinsically to do with threading/timing/waiting. that would be incorrect.

Comment: hey cory  :)   after two years ... to be honest I have lost the thread of the discussion.   "In modern C# we have async/await to accomplish what Unity intended" ...  Unity is a *frame based* engine, it's a totally different milieu.  Anyway cheers

Comment: And now, we have [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask).