# Unity Physics.OverlapSphere accessing objects that have already been destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making exploding barrels in Unity and using Physics.OverlapSphere to detect nearby rigidbodies and other exploding barrels. This is to move and trigger other exploding barrels to explode. The issue is when I'm using OverlapSphere in the triggered barrels it's accessing the previous barrel that triggered it which is destroyed, and I'm not entirely sure how.

[image]

This is error it gives me on line 67, where it says. `colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position ,explosionRadius);`

```
IEnumerator explode(bool exploLag)
{
    alreadyExploded = true;

    //moved the yield to the beginning
    //overlapsphere was finding barrels which were destroyed on the previous frame and then trying to access them causing errors
    if (exploLag == true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(explodeLag);
        Debug.Log("exploding later on due to explosion lag");
    }

    Debug.Log("explode was called");

    List<GameObject> existingBarrels = new List<GameObject>();
    Debug.Log("calm1");

    Collider[] colliders;
    colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position ,explosionRadius);
    Debug.Log("Calm2");

    Rigidbody exploRB;

    foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
    {
        Debug.Log(hit);

        if (hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("no rigidbody - cringe");
        }

        else if (hit.GetComponent<explosiveBarrel>() != null)
        {
            if (hit.GetComponent<explosiveBarrel>().alreadyExploded == true)
            {
                Debug.Log("Exploding barrel has already been made to explode");
                //so it doesnt try to explode it again and remove it 
                //will add an explosion force though so that its effected by the blast of this explosion also.

                //exploRB = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                //exploRB.AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, explosionPos, explosionRadius, 1f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }

            else
            {
                Debug.Log("ooo an existing barrel - ill save you later hehe uwu");
                //another barrel has been detected will be exploded on the next frame
                //this is too avoid it referencing this barrel aswell
                existingBarrels.Add(hit.gameObject);
                exploRB = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                exploRB.AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, transform.position, explosionRadius, 1f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }

        else if (hit == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Object doesnt exist anymore");
        }

        else
        {
            exploRB = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            exploRB.AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, transform.position, explosionRadius, 1f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            
            Debug.Log("I moved a non exploding object");
        }
    }       

    foreach (GameObject explosiveB in existingBarrels)
    {
        explosiveB.GetComponent<explosiveBarrel>().StartCoroutine(explode(true));
    }
    
    ps.Play();
    Destroy(gameObject); 
    Debug.Log("explode pog");
    yield return null;
}
```

My apologies for just flooding my question with my code but I have no idea what's really wrong.

Answer (score 0):

---

**TL; DR:** essentially I believe the problem with your code is that insufficient checks are leading to multiple calls to `explode` to explode a barrel that was already exploded.  Hence the error from Unity.

---

### Opening

I'm not sure why the need for a coroutine for this one.  A regular method would have sufficed.

Additionally, coroutines can be risky, ones that invoke themselves without any guard particularly so.<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>

### Issue

There are a few issues with the design of your code, particularly where and how checks are performed that governs if and when barrels explode.

Rather than checking the `alreadyExploded` flag and adding conditionally to the `existingBarrels` list:

```
if (hit.GetComponent<explosiveBarrel>().alreadyExploded == true) 
{
    .
    .
    .
}
else
{
    .
    .
    .
    existingBarrels.Add(hit.gameObject);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

...instead, I would perform the check like the following and do away with the list.  For extra protection you should use a *state machine* (via the new `BarrelStates` enumeration) for the barrels to prevent more than one call to explode a barrel:

```
// alreadyExploded is insufficent to protect against duplicate explosions 
enum BarrelStates
{
    Idle,
    Exploding,
    Exploded
}

IEnumerator explode(bool exploLag)
{
    if (State != Exploding)  // <-------- new guard to prevent duplicate destruction
        yield break;

   
    foreach (Collider hit in colliders)
    {
        var barrel = hit.GetComponent<explosiveBarrel>();

        // Don't explode a barrel already in the process of exploding
        if (barrel != null && !barrel.State == States.Idle ) 
        { 
            barrel.State = States.Exploding; // <---- new
            exploRB = hit.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            exploRB.AddExplosionForce(explosionForce, transform.position, explosionRadius, 1f, ForceMode.Impulse);

        }
    }

    State = States.Exploded; // Finally, set exploded state

    ps.Play();
    Destroy(gameObject); 
    Debug.Log("explode pog");
    yield return null;
}
```

### End notes

You need to be careful on holding references to Unity objects that are subject to destruction by Unity itself.  Not only is this because Unity is the thing responsible for the object creation in the first place, but also because Unity is a CLR Host and it can and will zap out all .NET objects (including `static`) during Domain Reload whilst using the Editor or using Play.<sup>3</sup> <sup>4</sup>

The effect is exactly the same as desktop Windows development using say *WinForms/WPF* and you attempt to use a `Pen`, `Brush` or `Font` that has already been `Disposed`.  Essentially both GDI objects and Unity have **non-managed counterparts**.

---

<sup>1</sup> Nelson, C, (formerly MSFT), *["C# Why shouldn't I ever use coroutines?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35817077/585968)*, Stack Overflow, March 2016, retrieved 2022-11-27

<sup>2</sup> Duncan, M, *["Implementing time-based delays in Unity 3D"](https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2022/10/06/implementing-time-based-delays-in-unity-3d/)*, October 2022, retrieved 2022-11-27

<sup>3</sup> *["Domain Reloading"](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html)*, Unity, retrieved 2022-11-27

<sup>4</sup> *["Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)*, Unity, retrieved 2022-11-27

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the code you've added to the end of your coroutine, not specifically the call to `OverlapSphere`.

Following the code from the beginning, what you're asking it to do is start an explosion, from which you're gathering all the barrels that are in the explosion sphere. Once you've gathered all these barrels into a list, you're asking to start the coroutine on those barrels, BUT you're telling the coroutine that's running, to use 'this' instance's `explode` IEnumerator/Coroutine. Shortly after that, you `Destroy` 'this'. The end result? Your new coroutines are trying to run code on an object that you just destroyed.

```cs
foreach (GameObject explosiveB in existingBarrels)
{
    // This next line is telling the OTHER component/class to use THIS instance of 'explode'.
    explosiveB.GetComponent<explosiveBarrel>().StartCoroutine(explode(true));
}
```

I was able to quickly mock up what I believe to be your intent, using your previous code to guide me, but rejigged. The result looks like this:

[image: Exploding Barrels]

The following code is what produced the above result. It should hopefully be quite self-explanatory. Comments added for clarity.

```cs
public class explosiveBarrel : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float explosionRadius;
    [SerializeField] private float explodeLag = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private float explosionForce;
    [SerializeField] private float explodedSnuffLife = 2;

    public bool alreadyExploded { get; private set; }


    // A public facing method to start the 'explode' coroutine on this object.
    public void Explode ( )
    {
        StartCoroutine ( explode ( true ) );
    }

    // The internal 'coroutine' to delay the explosion.
    private IEnumerator explode ( bool lag )
    {
        alreadyExploded = true;

        if ( lag )
        {
            Debug.Log ( "exploding later on due to explosion lag" );
            yield return new WaitForSeconds ( explodeLag );
        }

        foreach ( var hit in Physics.OverlapSphere ( transform.position, explosionRadius ) )
        {
            Debug.Log ( hit );

            if ( !hit.TryGetComponent<Rigidbody> ( out var rb ) )
            {
                Debug.Log ( $"Item didn't have an RB. [{hit.gameObject.name}]" );
                continue;
            }

            if ( hit.TryGetComponent<explosiveBarrel> ( out var eb ) )
            {
                // The hit target is a 'explosiveBarrel'. If not already exploded, call the public Explode method on that object.
                if ( !eb.alreadyExploded )
                    eb.Explode ( );
            }

            // Add the explosion force to the object, regardless of whether or not it's an 'explosiveBarrel'
            ps.Play ( );
            rb.AddExplosionForce ( explosionForce, transform.position, explosionRadius, 1f, ForceMode.Impulse );
        }

        // wait 'explodedSnuffLife' seconds, then destroy this object.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds ( explodedSnuffLife );
        Destroy ( gameObject );
    }
}
```

Now, as mentioned in another response by MickyD (who knows what he's talking about), Coroutines generally aren't "good" (subjective and controversial). The number one misconception is that a "coroutine" somehow runs in parallel to the code, that some sort of multitasking is going on. The reality is that the processing is just "sliced" into the current frame's update cycle. I generally won't use Coroutines in "real" code that I write. Having said that, they DO provide an already built, well tested, hugely documented, massively used in "tutorials" and easy mechanism to produce results. As with all things coding, there's usually many ways to achieve a result, and if a result can be achieved in much less code, with a clear intent, then there's an argument to not discount them *entirely*.

A possible update might be to add an "Explodeable" (no such word, but ...) tag to each object that can be exploded. Or, make sure that 'explodeable' objects are on the same layer. Personally, I'd be inclined to implement an IExplodeable interface, with an exposed `Explode` method. That way you could then search for not just `explosiveBarrel` components, but any `IExplodeable` that could explode when caught in a blast.