# Auto update a table after 10s using php

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, cron

I am new to php. 
I have a database of a turn based multiplayer game (game is made in unity 3d). Table GameTable stores the ids of two players ,their positions and a boolean to determine whose turn it is. 1 if player1's turn and 0 if player 2's turn.

I want that after every minute the position increments itself and the turn changes. I want this to happen automatically on the server side.

I am familiar with Cron jobs. But i don't want to create separate cron job for every entry in the table. Any ideas guys ?

Comment: Use google for this, it's pretty basic stuff. Once you have some code and it's still not working, you can ask again.

Comment: In unity use **Invoke()** to make timers and control your flow.  it's extremely simple.  google "unity3d Invoke" for a million examples.  it's one of the most basic things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking condition and calling continuous method with periods of delay unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807232/checking-condition-and-calling-continuous-method-with-periods-of-delay-unity)

Comment: more examples .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35970758/294884